# Problemas para cargar scripts de componentes angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

buenas! tengo un problema con mi codigo.
Hice componentes de mi sitio, y cuando pongo el script solo me levanta el ultimo..ya probe poniendo los archivos en carpetas diferentes, pero asi y todo sigo con el mismo problema. Desde ya, muchas gracias!
(todos los componentes, y el modulo ppal estan dentro de la carpeta app)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title>Theory by TEMPLATED</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Header -->
        <header-component></header-component>

        <!-- Banner -->
        <banner-component></banner-component>

        <!-- One -->
        <one-component></one-component>


        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="public/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="public/js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="public/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
        <script src="app/header/header.component.js"></script>
        <script src="app/banner/banner.component.js"></script>
        <script src="app/one/one.component.js"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

---

banner.component.js

```
(function(){
'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .component('bannerComponent', {
            bindings: {},
            templateUrl : 'app/banner/banner.html',
            controller : bannerCtrl
        })

        function bannerCtrl($scope){
            console.log('banner');
            $scope.welcome = "Welcooome to Theory";


        }
 }());
```

---

header.component.js

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
        angular
            .module('app', [])
            .component('headerComponent', {
                bindings: {},
                templateUrl : 'app/header/header.html',
                controller : headerCtrl
            })

            function headerCtrl($scope){
                console.log('header')
                $scope.logo = "theory";
                $scope.home = "Home";
                $scope.generic = 'Generic'
                $scope.elements = "Elements";

            }
}());
```

---

one.component.js

```
(function(){
'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .component('oneComponent', {
            bindings: {},
            templateUrl : 'app/One/one.html',
            controller : oneCtrl
        })

        function oneCtrl($scope){
            $scope.articulos = [
                {
                    titulos : "Magna tempus sed amet 1",
                    textos : "Morbi interdum mollis sapien. Sed ac risus. Phasellus lacinia, magna a ullamcorper laoreet, lectus arcu.",
                    btn : "More"
                },
                {
                    titulos : "Magna tempus sed amet 2",
                    textos : "Morbi interdum mollis sapien. Sed ac risus. Phasellus lacinia, magna a ullamcorper laoreet, lectus arcu.",
                    btn : "More"                        
                },
                {
                    titulos : "Magna tempus sed amet 3",
                    textos : "Morbi interdum mollis sapien. Sed ac risus. Phasellus lacinia, magna a ullamcorper laoreet, lectus arcu.",
                    btn : "More"                        
                },


            ]


        }
 }());
```

---

app.js

```
(function(){
'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app', []);
 }());
```

[image: y esta es la estrctura del proyecto]

Comment: quizas debas compartir el contenido js de los components.

Comment: @EmanuelFriedrich si, gracias, ahi puse todo!

Comment: No quiero ser tedioso pero si puedes revisa que el código no se ve bien. Revisa el markdown

Comment: @EmanuelFriedrich ahi puse toooodo, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

en principio algo me parece curioso.

Solo para one_component usas un path para el html así:

```
app/One/one.html
```

Para el resto lo veo en minuscula

```
app/header/header.html
app/banner/banner.html
```

No digo que sea eso, pero me llamó la atención

Comment: Si, lo note, y lo cambie, pero sigo en la misma....gracias